# Regex pattern for double-quoted strings in lsb.acct log

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find the regex pattern to match strings in LSF log files (lsb.acct).
Lines (log entries) in lsb.acct contain numbers and strings. Numbers are easy to match but I have a challenge with strings.
Strings are marked with surrounding "", characters " inside the string are escaped with another ".
*Example:*
line from lsb.acct:
`0 90 "dsfc --copt ""-c"" nfc_pa" 0.01 "" -1`  
contains the following fields:

```
0 (number)  
90 (number)  
dsfc --copt "-c" nfc_pa (string)  
0.01  
(empty string)  
-1 (number)
```

I tried /"([^"]*)"/ but it obviously doesn't solve the problem - doesn't catch the escaped double-quotes inside the string but cuts the string short.
I was thinking to add a look-ahead operator "(?=") to respect the escaped double-quote but I don't know where/how - doesn't work inside [].
Can anybody hint a proper regexp to match the string with respecting " as escape for " inside the string?

Comment: Your example string is `0 90 "dsfc --copt ""-c"" nfc_pa" 0.01 "" -1`, what is the expected outcome?

Comment: @ChristianBaumann, my expected outcome is a Python list of matched strings from re.findall(pattern,line) - with escape characters removed. For my example: re.findall(pattern,'0 90 "dsfc --copt ""-c"" nfc_pa" 0.01 "" -1') should return ['dsfc --copt "-c" nfc_pa', ''].

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for your feedback, I'm new to the site, I didn't realize the etiquette. I have spent considerable time looking for solution, please see my edited question.

Comment: Use `"((?:[^"]+|"")*)"|\S+`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zBwPW6/1).

Comment: This works! Doesn't cut out the escape " inside the string but this is sth I can live with :-) Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, greatly appreciated!